# Threadpool creates 4 more threads in python

Tags: python, multithreading

Very awkward behavior, with threading.Thread and .start() this behavior doesn't occur, but with ThreadPool (or multiprocessing.dummy Pool, same) I get more threads than the number I spawed + 1 (for the main). In fact, I always get 4 additional ghost threads. Could anyone explain what these threads are for?

Here's a test code:

```
import time
import threading
from concurrent import futures
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool

def test(x):
    print(f"Entering the thread {x}")
    print("ENUMERATE: ", threading.enumerate())
    print("IDENT: ", threading.current_thread().ident)
    print("ACTIVE: ", threading.active_count())
    print(x*x)
    time.sleep(2)
    print(f"Done..{x}")

pool = Pool(1)
pool.map(test, [1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

And the output:

```
Entering the thread 1
ENUMERATE:  [<_MainThread(MainThread, started 24256)>, <DummyProcess(Thread-1, started daemon 27240)>, <Thread(Thread-2, started daemon 20644)>, <Thread(Thread-3, started daemon 32324)>, <Thread(Thread-4, started daemon 14752)>]
IDENT:  27240
ACTIVE:  5
1
Done..1
Entering the thread 2
ENUMERATE:  [<_MainThread(MainThread, started 24256)>, <DummyProcess(Thread-1, started daemon 27240)>, <Thread(Thread-2, started daemon 20644)>, <Thread(Thread-3, started daemon 32324)>, <Thread(Thread-4, started daemon 14752)>]
IDENT:  27240
ACTIVE:  5
4
Done..2
Entering the thread 3
ENUMERATE:  [<_MainThread(MainThread, started 24256)>, <DummyProcess(Thread-1, started daemon 27240)>, <Thread(Thread-2, started daemon 20644)>, <Thread(Thread-3, started daemon 32324)>, <Thread(Thread-4, started daemon 14752)>]
IDENT:  27240
ACTIVE:  5
9
Done..3
Entering the thread 4
ENUMERATE:  [<_MainThread(MainThread, started 24256)>, <DummyProcess(Thread-1, started daemon 27240)>, <Thread(Thread-2, started daemon 20644)>, <Thread(Thread-3, started daemon 32324)>, <Thread(Thread-4, started daemon 14752)>]
IDENT:  27240
ACTIVE:  5
16
Done..4
Entering the thread 5
ENUMERATE:  [<_MainThread(MainThread, started 24256)>, <DummyProcess(Thread-1, started daemon 27240)>, <Thread(Thread-2, started daemon 20644)>, <Thread(Thread-3, started daemon 32324)>, <Thread(Thread-4, started daemon 14752)>]
IDENT:  27240
ACTIVE:  5
25
Done..5
Entering the thread 6
ENUMERATE:  [<_MainThread(MainThread, started 24256)>, <DummyProcess(Thread-1, started daemon 27240)>, <Thread(Thread-2, started daemon 20644)>, <Thread(Thread-3, started daemon 32324)>, <Thread(Thread-4, started daemon 14752)>]
IDENT:  27240
ACTIVE:  5
36
Done..6
```

You can see there are always 5 threads active.

Comment: As you can see from the `IDENT: 27240`, there is only one worker thread.  I can't see anywhere in the [multiprocessing docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) that says that other threads won't be made for the Pool's own internal use.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with python, but they could be for performance reasons. Keeping a bunch of sleeping threads ready to wake up (and reuse) is more efficient than starting new ones.